# Setting up WIki on a Debian OS. Having issues with config after installation

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb

This is all a learning experience for me, i have no previous experience with linux or terminals.

````
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
201107 00:16:42 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
201107 00:16:43 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ # sudo mysql -u root -p
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mysql> CREATE USER 'new_mysql_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'THISpasswordSHOULDbeCHANGED';
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mysql> quit;
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'pi'@'localhost'
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mysql> CREATE USER 'new_mysql_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'THISpasswordSHOULDbeCHANGED';
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mysql> quit;
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'pi'@'localhost'```
````

Comment: Please [search this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+access+denied+for+user+%40) before posting a new question, as chances are quite good that it has been asked here before.

Comment: I see, well thanks.

Comment: I'm still having issues with user permissions, When i try to edit the mysql.cnf doc from the file manager with a txt editor my changes are denied.

Comment: Then that would make this an OS question, not a programming question, and make it off-topic here. Try [unix.se] instead.

Comment: Im grateful and i've asked on the OS site, I know now to spot similar questions before i post. At the moment i haven't gotten any replies and the questions I've looked at have been similar but the fixes don't seem to fit my circumstance. It seems like i must be missing something fundamental at a really basic level here. So, I've got to ask, Have you spotted a misstep i have made by the information i gave. Can you deduce the source of the obstacle and Can you point me in the right direction?Are there any other methods of configuration or does it seem to you my issue lay within my user settings?

Answer (score 0):

When you installed mysql, were you prompted to establish a password for "root"?

You do not talk to `mysqld`; it is the server.  Instead, use `mysql` as a *client*; it will talk to the server mysqld.

At a prompt (such as `pi@raspberrypi:~ $`), enter

```
mysql -u root -p
```

That command does not need `sudo`.  And it should not be commented out (by `#`)

If you provided a password for `root`, the `-p` causes it to prompt you for root's password.  Enter it.  If you did not provide a password for "root", don't use `-p`

Note:  Debian has a `root` *and* MySQL has a `root`; they are *independent of each other*.

Now "root@localhost" is allowed to do `CREATE USER` and most other commands.  That is, you won't get the "Access denied" error.

See if you get that far.  Then look for examples on this forum and other places on the internet.